# Возможности Java

Tags: java

Добрый день. Я начинающий программист с небольшим опытом программирования на python и c++. Хотел бы узнать, стоит ли изучать Java и какими возможностями обладает этот язык программирования(т.е. что можно написать на Java).

Comment: всеми, которые вам могут понадобиться, и даже гораздо больше

Answer (score 4, accepted):

На Java пишут корпоративные порталы, веб-приложения и веб-сервисы, биллинги, трейдинговых роботов, приложения под мобильные платформы, софт для умных холодильников, телевизоров и банкоматов, в меньшей степени десктопные приложения и иногда даже игры.

UPD0. Чуть не забыл. Почти вымершие апплеты для браузеров и ныне здравствующие апплеты для SIM и Smart-карт тоже на Java.

UPD1. Да, и еще на JVM-совместимых языках можно сайтики писать.

Answer (score 3):

Тут все зависит от того кем вы себя хотите видеть в будущем - если интерпрайз разработчиком то учите джаву.

Answer (score 1):

Стоит еще упомянуть, что Java используется для разработки под Android и это направление сейчас очень активно развивается, в отличии от некоторых устаревших технологий.